# Error while upgrading rails 2 to 3 `const_get': uninitialized constant ActionView::ActionViewError (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to upgrade a rails 2 app to rails3 using rails upgrader gem , But starting the server show following error , what could be the possible reason

```
  $bundle exec rails server
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/haml-4.0.5/lib/haml/parser.rb:86: warning: regexp has invalid interval
    DEPRECATION WARNING: RAILS_ENV is deprecated. Please use ::Rails.env. (called from /home/user/projects/fedena/config/application.rb:5)
    => Booting Mongrel
    => Rails 3.0.9 application starting in development on http://127.0.0.1:3000
    => Call with -d to detach
    => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
    Exiting
    /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:70:in `const_get': uninitialized constant ActionView::ActionViewError (NameError)
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:70:in `local_constants'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:70:in `each'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:70:in `local_constants'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:68:in `each'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:68:in `local_constants'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/activesupport-3.0.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/module/introspection.rb:86:in `local_constant_names'
        from /home/user/projects/fedena/config.ru:3
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
        from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-head/gems/rack-1.2.8/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
        from /home/user/projects/fedena/config.ru:1:in `new'
        from /home/user/projects/fedena/config.ru:1
```

Comment: You haven't updated the ruby you are using ? I think support to ruby 1.8.7 has been dropped for now .

Comment: @CaffeineCoder ruby 1.8.7 is supported upto rails 3.2.x :-)

Comment: Where are the plugins located ? If you are updating to rails 3 , then they have a new folder to put into . PS - I haven't yet ported a rails 2 app to rails 3 but i am doing the best i can :)

Comment: @CaffeineCoder : still in vendor/plugins , But it is just deprecated not obsoleted ,